# How to reverse a certain number of objects in a Linked List?

Tags: java

Here is the method I have so far. I'm not sure how to go about this. I want the method to take a int parameter of how many of the objects the user wants reversed in the linked list.

```
public void reverseFirstFew(int howMany) // NOT DONE 
{
   ListIterator iterator = listIterator();
   Object temp = null;

   if(howMany <= 0){
       throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
   }
   if(howMany > size()){
       throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
   }



}
```

I also have a custom ListIterator class that I made. Here are the methods in it.

```
public ListIterator listIterator()
{
  return new LinkedListIterator();
}


private class LinkedListIterator implements ListIterator
{

  private Node position;
  private Node previous;

  // Constructs an iterator that points to the front
  // of the linked list.   of the linked list.
  public LinkedListIterator()
  {
     position = null;
     previous = null;
  }

 // Moves the iterator past the next element, and returns
 // the traversed element's data.
  public Object next()
  {
     if (!hasNext())
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
     previous = position; // Remember for remove

     if (position == null)
        position = first;
     else
        position = position.next;

     return position.data;
  }

  // Tests if there is an element after the iterator position  position
  public boolean hasNext()
  {
     if (position == null)
        return first != null;
     else
        return position.next != null;
  }

  // Adds an element after the iterator position
  // and moves the iterator to the inserted element.
  public void add(Object element)
  {
     if (position == null)
     {
        addFirst(element);
        position = first;
     }
     else
     {
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.data = element;
        newNode.next = position.next;
        position.next = newNode;
        position = newNode;
     }
     previous = position;
  }

// Removes the last traversed element. This method may
// only be called after a call to the next() method.
  public void remove()
  {
     if (previous == position)
        throw new IllegalStateException();

     if (position == first)
     {
        removeFirst();
     }
     else
     {
        previous.next = position.next;
     }
     position = previous;
  }

  // Sets the last traversed element to a different value
  public void set(Object element)
  {
     if (position == null)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
     position.data = element;
  }
}//end of
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone could guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Which items should be reversed? The first, the last, some other combination...?

Comment: However many the user wants starting from the beginning. Left to right

Comment: One way to do this would be to get a sub-list of 'how many', reverse that whole list, then join the two lists together again.

Comment: @markspace that's what I was thinking, but I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: Are you using a `List` from the standard library, or are you implementing your own list from scratch?

Comment: If using a standard java `List`, you could use `Collections.reverse`

Comment: @markspace No need to join lists back together. The sub-list is a "view" and can be reversed in-place. See my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`List.subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) and [`Collections.reverse(List<?> list)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse-java.util.List-):

```
Collections.reverse(list.subList(0, howMany));
```

Works for both [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

*Example*

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9));
Collections.reverse(list.subList(0, 4));
System.out.println(list);
```

*Output*

```
[4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

As for why this works, quoting javadoc of `subList`:

> Returns a **view** of the portion of this list between the specified `fromIndex`, inclusive, and `toIndex`, exclusive. (If `fromIndex` and `toIndex` are equal, the returned list is empty.) The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa. The returned list supports all of the optional list operations supported by this list.
>
> This method eliminates the need for explicit range operations (of the sort that commonly exist for arrays). Any operation that expects a list can be used as a range operation by passing a subList view instead of a whole list. For example, the following idiom removes a range of elements from a list:
>
> ```
> list.subList(from, to).clear();
> ```

Comment: Beat me to it by literally less than a minute.  This works because `subList()` returns a **view** into the parent list.  So reversing the sub-list also reverses the parent.  **Always read the docs, this can mess you up bad.** But here's it's an advantage, because we don't have to do the final join.

Comment: @Andreas we have to use the custom linked list, we can't use the utility one...this is a homework assignment

Comment: @Suds2 If you have to implement the reverse yourself, then you can't use this answer, but if your list implements the `subList` method correctly, you could use the `Collections.reverse()` for that part, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give the same answer as Andreas, because damnit I coded this up and he posted just as I put the answer in my clipboard to paste it. >:-p

```
public class ReverseList
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<Integer> result = reverseFirst( Arrays.asList( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ), 4 );
      System.out.println( result );
   }

   private static List<Integer> reverseFirst( List<Integer> asList, int howMany )
   {
      List<Integer> sub = asList.subList( 0, howMany );
      Collections.reverse( sub );
      return asList;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually a good solution for reversing is to use a stack.
So what I would do:

```
Stack<Object> myStack;
Iterate through my list for as many elements as the user specified (howmany)
     push each element into the stack.

Object JoinHere = the next element in the list;
Now, reconstruct the reversed part of the list using the stack (pop,peek).
When you pop the last element from the stack, make the last element's next    
pointer point to JoinHere.
```

Of course, you should add error checking to for example, e.g.: is howmany bigger than the list...

Comment: @Suds2 the others have submitted a good solution already. If it is a school project (e.g. data structures and algorithms), and you need to implement this. Then write back, and I can give you a sample. Otherwise, if you would like to use it as part of an application or anything, then as I said, the others have probably given a good solution for that.